# Set the Listbox Selectedindex when textbox is selected WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have set the DataTemplate for the Listbox item such that it contains an TextBlock and an TextBox.

The problem I am facing is, when the list is displayed its selectionindex is -1, and suppose if the user taps directly into the textbox of any of the listitem then the that Listitem hasn't been set an the selecteditem of the listbox.

How can I change/set the selectedindex/item of the listbox when the user focus directly to the textbox?

---

Ok let me be more clear

my ListBox DataTemplate is as follows

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="325"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ProdName}" Margin="0,5,0,0" Width="315" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="0"  ></TextBlock>
       <TextBox InputScope="Number" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProdQty}"  TextAlignment="Center" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtQty" GotFocus="ClearZero" LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus"></TextBox>

      </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Now when the page is opened the listbox if populated and its SelectedIndex is -1. Now suppose if the user taps(or sets focus) directly into the say 3rd TextBox (i.e the textbox of the third ListItem in the listbox), i want the listbox SelectedIndex to be changed from -1 to 2 (3rd items index).

When i am retriving the SelectedIndex of the ListBox when the 3rd(say) TextBox receives focus, its returning an value of -1.

Hope i am clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tapping on it sets SelectedItem and SelectObject, so it's perfectly reasonable for them to be -1 and null initially.

If you want to initialise it then just set selectedindex to one of the items in the list, after it's populated. NB check to see if items.count > 0 before you do that.

Comment: My problem isnt about setting  the listbox.SelectedIndex = something, i want to know how to set the listbox selectedindex when the focus is directly into the textbox of the listitem (textbox is an member of the datatemplate of the listiem)

Comment: Confusion of terms mate, I thought you meant ListBox as in standard ListBox control. Off the top of my head without more info, I'd assume the Item had a Parent (or it could be inferred) and do something like this.Parent.SelectedItem = Parent.Items.Find(this)